# How to catch exceptions in controller's actions properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is the following code:

```
def index
  @posts = User.find_by(login: params[:user_id]).posts
end
```

As you can see this code can generate exception if there is no user with some login (nil pointer exception). How can I catch this exception and handle it properly? I know how to catch exceptions in Ruby, but I want to know how to do in a good Rails style. The same problem may occur  in different controllers - may be I should create an action wrapper, catch exception and render 500 error?

Comment: You can use [`rescue_from`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: good rails style is not to allow the exception (at least that one) to being raised. so you can use anither form: `posts = User.where(login: params[:user_id]).first.try(:posts)`

Comment: What about integration exceptions or anything else ? Should this be done in BaseController, or you should wrap every action in try-catch blocks (rails begin - rescue)?

Comment: @NickCatib if you strongly need to catch the exception that isn't of your code, just use the handling as it was specified by `@avlazarov` below

Comment: There is no better way then to wrap every action that could throw something? Wouldn't be better to have exception handling on one place (Base controller for instance) and then do everything we should there ?

Comment: @NickCatib it depends on the code which is being written by the developer. In this case there are no explicilty stated (or better) approach. The develope can catch the excpetion if he just do a redirect to root `/`, if any other action required the developer can catch other exception action specific to do the specific things.

Comment: I recently read that it's better to use `fetch` method instead of `try` in ruby.  `User.where(login: params[:user_id]).first.fetch(:posts, "Missing")` how about this? I m not sure is it valid or not..

Comment: @HetalKhunti please check in `pry` wheither the `nil` class have the `#fetch` method, if yes you can use the `#fetch` when you have to return a default value instead of `nil`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to use ApplicationController's [rescue_from](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :record_not_found

  private

  def record_not_found
    render 'my/custom/template', status: 404
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def index
  @posts = User.find_by!(login: params[:user_id]).posts
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => error
  # handle user not found case
end
```

You can also use `rescue_from` http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html if you want to catch the error globally for the controller.